# fill matrix from a column and a row in data frame using apply method(pandas)

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

So i made a function that uses two variables, but i want to use a method apply on the dataframe so the function will use  every value from a row and column to make a new table. So the  the output look something like this. Btw im pretty new to python. I have searched but i didnt find anything.

```
  Input:
   a b c d e f g 
a
b
c
d
e
```

Output

```
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g 
a  aa ab ac ad ae af ag 
b  ba bb bc bd be bf bg
c  ca cb cc cd ce cf cg
d  da db dc dd de df dg
e  ea eb ec ed ee ef eg
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Instead of searching, I would recommend thinking about the problem. It would seem there are a number of good solutions you can find.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you start with the lists of rows and columns, and both contain strings and nothing but strings:

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

columns = list("abcdefg")
rows = list("abcde")
```

Take a Cartesian products of the lists, join the items in each pair, and convert the list to a NumPy array:

```
products = np.array([''.join(x) for x in product(rows, columns)])
```

Reshape the list into a rectangular table, add row and column headers:

```
pd.DataFrame(products.reshape(-1, len(columns)), index=rows, columns=columns)
#    a   b   c   d   e   f   g
#a  aa  ab  ac  ad  ae  af  ag
#b  ba  bb  bc  bd  be  bf  bg
#c  ca  cb  cc  cd  ce  cf  cg
#d  da  db  dc  dd  de  df  dg
#e  ea  eb  ec  ed  ee  ef  eg
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the data frame then using `apply`

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=list('abcdefg'),index=list('abcdefg')).apply(lambda x : x.name+x.index)
Out[713]: 
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g
a  aa  ba  ca  da  ea  fa  ga
b  ab  bb  cb  db  eb  fb  gb
c  ac  bc  cc  dc  ec  fc  gc
d  ad  bd  cd  dd  ed  fd  gd
e  ae  be  ce  de  ee  fe  ge
f  af  bf  cf  df  ef  ff  gf
g  ag  bg  cg  dg  eg  fg  gg
```